# Handling threads in server application after clients disconnect

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, server, winsock

I'm currently working on simple HTTP server. I use Winsock and standard threads from C++11. For each connected (accepted) client there is new thread created.

```
std::map<SOCKET, std::thread> threads;

bool server_running = true;
while(server_running) {
    SOCKET client_socket;
    client_socket = accept(listen_socket, NULL, NULL);
    if(client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        // some error handling
    }
    threads[client_socket] = std::thread(clientHandler, client_socket);
}
```

`clientHandler` function looks generally like this:

```
while(1) {
    while(!all_data_received) {
        bytes_received = recv(client_socket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if(bytes_received > 0) {
            // do something
        } else {
            goto client_cleanup;
        }
    }
    // do something
}
client_cleanup: // we also get here when Connection: close was received
closesocket(client_socket);
```

And here we come to my problem - how to handle all the threads which ended but haven't been joined with main thread and references to them still exist in `threads` map?

The simplest solution would be probably to iterate over `threads` frequently  (e.q. from another thread?) and join and delete those which returned.

Please share your expertise. :)

<sub>PS. Yes, I know about *thread pool* pattern. I'm not using it in my app (for better or worse). I'm looking for answer concerning my current architecture.</sub>

Comment: I don't know the scale of your application, but the "one thread per client" server model is known not to be scalable. Consider using asynchronous requests on your sockets and forget about handling threads yourself. After all, raw threads are also called the modern day goto (which ironically you happen to be using in your example)

Comment: It's for learning purposes only, to be exact.

Comment: Nothing wrong with learning to do things properly from the start. Personally, I would find it wasteful if you had learned to make a server one way, only to have to learn an entirely new way once the time comes to make a real application. Still, you're free to do as you like, of course.

Comment: @KABoissonneault What do you mean by "asynchronous requests on sockets" and forgetting about handling threads myself? Should I use only one thread and move on to another socket when there's no data to receive on current one?

Comment: @KABoissonneault Can you recommend me better error handling solution than those `goto`s? I didn't want to repeat myself.

Comment: That should be part of your research, or be another separate question if your research fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution? Just [`detach()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) after you start the thread. This will mean that once the thread terminates the resources will be cleaned up and you don't need to keep the `std::map<SOCKET, std::thread> threads`.

```
std::thread(clientHandler, client_socket).detach();
```

Otherwise create a thread-safe LIFO queue where during cleanup you push the socket to it.

Then in the main loop you alternately check `accept` and that queue and when the queue has sockets in them you do `threads.erase(socket);` for each socket in the queue.

However if you do that then you may as well putt he LIFO in the other direction and use a thread pool.

Comment: Somehow I thought that `detach`-ing a thread won't be a good (clean) solution. Does it have any clear drawbacks?

Comment: @Luke just that there will be no more reference to the thread object anymore. But given that you only kept them to be cleaned up that's not issue for you.